# how to answer the question 'what is it that '

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please tell me how to answer this question

> What it is that your friends may not admit?

a. Our friends may not admit that they feel insecure.
 b. It is their insecure feeling that our friend may not admit.

Which answer is more appropriate, **a** or **b**?

Comment: What's your take on it?

Comment: Is the phrase at the beginning "What it is" or "What is it?" One is a very informal colloquaism that doesn't really even fit the sentence, and your title contradicts your example.

Answer (score 1):

You could rephrase this question as

> What may your friends not admit?

To which the answer would be

a. That they feel insecure.

"What is it that" is a speech construct common in informal talk. (Similar to "at" on the end of a "Where's the *object* at")

It can be quite difficult to work out what to remove from this kind of sentence, but it's possible to work through from the complex answer to a simpler one. Note that the intermediate steps aren't incorrect, I'm just showing the thought process used to simplify the language.

> What it is that your friends may not admit?
>
> What is the thing that your friends may not admit?
>
> What thing may your friends not admit?
>
> What may your friends not admit?